# How to sort an array by boolean filed in swift?

Tags: swift

I have a class defined like this:

```
class someClass {
   var isCompleted = false
}
```

how to sort the list of the `someClass`? if want to move the completed items to the top of the list.

Comment: How big is the list? I think two `.filter`s or even a loop will likely be clearer to reaso about (and likely faster but who cares)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You mean filter it and combine the result?

Comment: Yes, you can also directly sort it but a sort on a boolean is just weird

Comment: @A-Live Filter it and combine the result, but maybe there are some better ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can sort according to the boolean property by converting
the values to `Int`:

```
let arrayOfClasses =  ... // array of classes

let sortedArrayOfClasses = sorted(arrayOfClasses) {
    Int($0.isCompleted) > Int($1.isCompleted)
}
```

Or with "in-situ" sort:

```
var arrayOfClasses =  ... // array of classes

sort(&arrayOfClasses) {
    Int($0.isCompleted) > Int($1.isCompleted)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

parameter closure for `sort` or `sorted` returns `true` iff the first parameter must be ordered before the second, otherwise `false`.

So you can:

```
let array = [ ... ]

let sortedArray = array.sorted { a, b in
    a.isCompleted && !b.isCompleted
}
```

Comment: Works great, thank you! I shortened it to `array.sorted { $0.isCompleted && !$1.isCompleted }`

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourArrayOfBooleans:[SomeClass] = ...

var sortedArrayOfBooleans:[SomeClass] = []
var tmpArray:[SomeClass] = []

for ar in yourArrayOfBooleans
{
     if ar.isCompleted
     {
          sortedArrayOfBooleans.append(ar)
     }
     else
     {
         tmpArray.append(ar)
     }
}
sortedArrayOfBooleans += tmpArray
```